# Compilation error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Goodmorning from Holland,

I'm just n00bing around VBA, and keep bumping in to said compilation error as seen in this screenshot; [image: Screenshot]
I would like to see this solved, but i want to learn how to kill these horrible errors. What is my mistake?

Comment: Edited it, so the error shows in the screen.

Comment: Just count your `If`s and your `End If`s and you will see it.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, you are missing one `End If`-Statement: You are opening three `If`-Cases, but close only two of them. (I guess you want to put the missing one before the line saying `If not Rng Is Nothing Then`, thus closing the statement `If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then`)

For the future: Proper indentation of your code will help you spot errors like this easily!

Comment: Thanks for making the way to think about indentation clear to me. Second good answer on one of my questions, hero.

Comment: @RobExcel you're welcome :-) One more thing: Please try to add Code in writing rather than as screenshot. This makes it easier for us to try around with it without having to type everything from scratch!

Answer (score 2):

Your "If Not Rng Is Nothing Then" is missing an "End If"

It should be more obvious if you indent correctly your code.